# Distance from a point to a complement of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: x^2+y^2 \leq 1\}$ be the unit disk and consider $U$ be a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $D \subset U$. Since $D$ is compact and $U^c$ is closed, $\operatorname{dist}(D,U^c)=r>0$.

[image]

Intuitively, it seems that $\|y\| \geq r+1$ for all $y \in U^c$ (or $B[0,1+r] \subset U$).

> **My question:** Is this statement true? More generally, can we generalize this to any metric space?
>
> **My attempt:** Let $y \in U^c$ and $\displaystyle x=\frac{y}{\|y\|}$, then $y \in D^c=\{z \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:\|z\|>1\}$ and
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> \|y\|^2&=&\|y-x+x\|^2\\
> &=& \|y-x\|^2+2(x,y-x)+\|x\|^2\\
> &\geq& r^2+2\left(\frac{y}{\|y\|},\|y\|\frac{y}{\|y\|}-\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right)+1\\
> &=&r^2+2\left(\frac{y}{\|y\|},\frac{y}{\|y\|}(\|y\|-1) \right)+1\\
> &=&r^2+2(\|y\|-1)+1\\
> &\geq&r^2+1,
> \end{eqnarray*}
> since $\|y\|-1>0$. But this inequality does not provide the inclusion that I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have obtained $\|y\|^2\geq r^2+2(\|y\|-1)+1$. Continuing with this,
$$(\|y\|-1)^2=\|y\|^2-2\|y\|+1\geq r^2\implies\|y\|\geq 1+r$$

I don't think you can generalize to arbitrary metric space, though, for two reasons.

- A metric space may not be equipped with a norm, i.e. $\|y\|$ may not be defined.
- Even though we work with normed vector spaces, the unit ball may not be compact.

But the generalization to high dimensional Euclidean spaces should be fine.

Comment: Is there any counter example for a general metric space (different from the Euclidean one)?

Comment: @VictorHugo Riesz' theorem states that if a normed vector space has compact unit ball, then it is finite dimensional. In other words, any inifinite dimensional n.v.s. does not have a compact unit ball. My reference is Brezis' functional analysis.